# Trying to clear all input boxes on click

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so I am making a madlibs website anyways, I am trying to get all input box's to clear after they submit their answer. I thought I could do this by putting all the variables in a array but I guess not?

Would appreciate the help!

The clear function and variable is at the bottom of the c/p in the code block.
HTML CODE (Yes my JavaScript in the HTML file for right now I know):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Madlibs</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Godfather ipsum dolor sit amet. If anything in this life is certain, if history has taught us anything, it is that you can
    <span id="noun1">________</span> anyone. My father's name was Antonio Andolini... and this is for you. We're both part of the same hypocrisy, senator, but never think it applies to my family. I see you took the name of the <span id="noun2">____________</span>.
    What was your father's name? Sonny, please don't do anything. Please don't do anything.
  </p>
  <p>
    Only don't tell me you're <span id="noun3">____________</span>. Because it insults my intelligence and makes me very angry. What's the matter with you, huh? What am I going to do? Am I going to make that
    <span id="noun4">____________</span> an orphan before he's born? Michael, you never told me you knew Johnny Fontane! Don Corleone, I am honored and grateful that you have invited me to your home on the wedding day of your daughter. And may their first
    child be a
    <span id="noun5">____________</span> child. You talk about vengeance. Is vengeance going to bring your son back to you? Or my boy to me?
  </p>

  <form>
    <label> A Noun: <input type="text" id="noun1Input" value="" /> </label>
    <label>
            Another Noun: <input type="text" id="noun2Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <label>
            Third the Noun: <input type="text" id="noun3Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <label>
            The Fourth Noun: <input type="text" id="noun4Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <label>
            The Noun of the Fifth: <input type="text" id="noun5Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <button type="button" id="clickMe">Click me</button>
  </form>
  <div id="backgroundimg"></div>
</body>
<script>
  const myButton = document.getElementById("clickMe");
  const noun1 = document.getElementById("noun1");
  const noun2 = document.getElementById("noun2");
  const noun3 = document.getElementById("noun3");
  const noun4 = document.getElementById("noun4");
  const noun5 = document.getElementById("noun5");
  const noun1Input = document.getElementById("noun1Input");
  const noun2Input = document.getElementById("noun2Input");
  const noun3Input = document.getElementById("noun3Input");
  const noun4Input = document.getElementById("noun4Input");
  const noun5Input = document.getElementById("noun5Input");

  myButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    noun1.innerHTML = noun1Input.value;
    noun2.innerHTML = noun2Input.value;
    noun3.innerHTML = noun3Input.value;
    noun4.innerHTML = noun4Input.value;
    noun5.innerHTML = noun5Input.value;
  });

  var entry = document.getElementById(["noun1Input", "noun2Input", "noun3Input"]);
  clear = document.getElementById("clickMe");

  function clearfield() {
    entry.value = "";
  }

  clear.addEventListener("click", clearfield, false);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: `formReference.reset()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this preserves most of your code and just fixes what wasn't working.  The solution above is a bit better as the javascript is minimized

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Madlibs</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Godfather ipsum dolor sit amet. If anything in this life is certain, if history has taught us anything, it is that you can
    <span id="noun1">________</span> anyone. My father's name was Antonio Andolini... and this is for you. We're both part of the same hypocrisy, senator, but never think it applies to my family. I see you took the name of the <span id="noun2">____________</span>.
    What was your father's name? Sonny, please don't do anything. Please don't do anything.
  </p>
  <p>
    Only don't tell me you're <span id="noun3">____________</span>. Because it insults my intelligence and makes me very angry. What's the matter with you, huh? What am I going to do? Am I going to make that
    <span id="noun4">____________</span> an orphan before he's born? Michael, you never told me you knew Johnny Fontane! Don Corleone, I am honored and grateful that you have invited me to your home on the wedding day of your daughter. And may their first
    child be a
    <span id="noun5">____________</span> child. You talk about vengeance. Is vengeance going to bring your son back to you? Or my boy to me?
  </p>

  <form>
    <label> A Noun: <input type="text" id="noun1Input" value="" /> </label>
    <label>
            Another Noun: <input type="text" id="noun2Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <label>
            Third the Noun: <input type="text" id="noun3Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <label>
            The Fourth Noun: <input type="text" id="noun4Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <label>
            The Noun of the Fifth: <input type="text" id="noun5Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <button type="button" id="clickMe">Click me</button>
  </form>
  <div id="backgroundimg"></div>
</body>
<script>
  const myButton = document.getElementById("clickMe");
  const noun1 = document.getElementById("noun1");
  const noun2 = document.getElementById("noun2");
  const noun3 = document.getElementById("noun3");
  const noun4 = document.getElementById("noun4");
  const noun5 = document.getElementById("noun5");
  const noun1Input = document.getElementById("noun1Input");
  const noun2Input = document.getElementById("noun2Input");
  const noun3Input = document.getElementById("noun3Input");
  const noun4Input = document.getElementById("noun4Input");
  const noun5Input = document.getElementById("noun5Input");

  myButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    noun1.innerHTML = noun1Input.value;
    noun2.innerHTML = noun2Input.value;
    noun3.innerHTML = noun3Input.value;
    noun4.innerHTML = noun4Input.value;
    noun5.innerHTML = noun5Input.value;
  });

  var entry = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  clear = document.getElementById("clickMe");

  function clearfield() {
    for(var i = 0; i<entry.length;i++){
    
    entry[i].value="";
    }
  }

  clear.addEventListener("click", clearfield, false);
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

this statement is messing you up:

```
var entry = document.getElementById(["noun1Input", "noun2Input", "noun3Input"]);
```

What's that suppose to do?

```js
function clearAll(){
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');    
  
  for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){  
     var noun = 'noun' + (i+1);
     var elem = document.getElementById(noun);
     elem.innerHTML = inputs[i].value; 
  
     inputs[i].value="";
   }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Madlibs</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Godfather ipsum dolor sit amet. If anything in this life is certain, if history has taught us anything, it is that you can
    <span id="noun1">________</span> anyone. My father's name was Antonio Andolini... and this is for you. We're both part of the same hypocrisy, senator, but never think it applies to my family. I see you took the name of the <span id="noun2">____________</span>.
    What was your father's name? Sonny, please don't do anything. Please don't do anything.
  </p>
  <p>
    Only don't tell me you're <span id="noun3">____________</span>. Because it insults my intelligence and makes me very angry. What's the matter with you, huh? What am I going to do? Am I going to make that
    <span id="noun4">____________</span> an orphan before he's born? Michael, you never told me you knew Johnny Fontane! Don Corleone, I am honored and grateful that you have invited me to your home on the wedding day of your daughter. And may their first
    child be a
    <span id="noun5">____________</span> child. You talk about vengeance. Is vengeance going to bring your son back to you? Or my boy to me?
  </p>

  <form>
    <label> A Noun: <input type="text" id="noun1Input" value="" /> </label>
    <label>
            Another Noun: <input type="text" id="noun2Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <label>
            Third the Noun: <input type="text" id="noun3Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <label>
            The Fourth Noun: <input type="text" id="noun4Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <label>
            The Noun of the Fifth: <input type="text" id="noun5Input" value="" />
          </label>
    <button type="button" id="clickMe" onClick='clearAll()'>Click me</button>
  </form>
  <div id="backgroundimg"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I knew that was messing me up, I mean I was hoping/guessing, there was a way to get each input by the inputs ID name, didn’t know you get the element by tag name...

Answer (score 0):

**Is this what you are trying to achieve ? (Done in the most crude way)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Madlibs</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Godfather ipsum dolor sit amet. If anything in this life is certain, if
      history has taught us anything, it is that you can
      <span id="noun1">________</span> anyone. My father's name was Antonio
      Andolini... and this is for you. We're both part of the same hypocrisy,
      senator, but never think it applies to my family. I see you took the name
      of the <span id="noun2">____________</span>. What was your father's name?
      Sonny, please don't do anything. Please don't do anything.
    </p>
    <p>
      Only don't tell me you're <span id="noun3">____________</span>. Because it
      insults my intelligence and makes me very angry. What's the matter with
      you, huh? What am I going to do? Am I going to make that
      <span id="noun4">____________</span> an orphan before he's born? Michael,
      you never told me you knew Johnny Fontane! Don Corleone, I am honored and
      grateful that you have invited me to your home on the wedding day of your
      daughter. And may their first child be a
      <span id="noun5">____________</span> child. You talk about vengeance. Is
      vengeance going to bring your son back to you? Or my boy to me?
    </p>

    <form>
      <label> A Noun: <input type="text" id="noun1Input" value="" /> </label>
      <label>
        Another Noun: <input type="text" id="noun2Input" value="" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Third the Noun: <input type="text" id="noun3Input" value="" />
      </label>
      <label>
        The Fourth Noun: <input type="text" id="noun4Input" value="" />
      </label>
      <label>
        The Noun of the Fifth: <input type="text" id="noun5Input" value="" />
      </label>
      <button type="button" id="clickMe">Click me</button>
    </form>
    <div id="backgroundimg"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const myButton = document.getElementById("clickMe");
    const noun1 = document.getElementById("noun1");
    const noun2 = document.getElementById("noun2");
    const noun3 = document.getElementById("noun3");
    const noun4 = document.getElementById("noun4");
    const noun5 = document.getElementById("noun5");
    const noun1Input = document.getElementById("noun1Input");
    const noun2Input = document.getElementById("noun2Input");
    const noun3Input = document.getElementById("noun3Input");
    const noun4Input = document.getElementById("noun4Input");
    const noun5Input = document.getElementById("noun5Input");

    myButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      noun1.innerHTML = noun1Input.value;
      noun2.innerHTML = noun2Input.value;
      noun3.innerHTML = noun3Input.value;
      noun4.innerHTML = noun4Input.value;
      noun5.innerHTML = noun5Input.value;
      
      noun1Input.value = ""
      noun2Input.value = ""
      noun3Input.value = ""
      noun4Input.value = ""
      noun5Input.value = ""
    });

  </script>
</html>
```

**You can do a much better job wit jquery. So Read**

Comment: No jQuery needed with modern ES6 and the DOM API `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).forEach(node => node.value = '');`